# Using Spotify/background music with camera open

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio, avaudiosession

I have an app that needs to have:

- Background music playing while using the app (eg. spotify)
- Background music playing while watching movie from AVPlayer
- Stop the music when recording a video

Like Snapchat, the camera-viewcontroller is part of a "swipeview" and therefore always on.

**However, when opening and closing the app, the music makes a short "crack" noise/sound that ruins the music.**

I recorded it here:
https://soundcloud.com/morten-stulen/hacky-sound-ios
(3 occurrences)

I use these settings for changing the AVAudiosession in the appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
     do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,withOptions: 
                [AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.MixWithOthers,
                 AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker])
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
```

I use the LLSimpleCamera control for video recording and I've set the session there to:

```
_session.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = NO;
```

It seems others have the same problem with other camera libraries as well:
https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder/issues/127

https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder/issues/224

This guy removed the audioDeviceInput, but I kinda need that for recording video.
https://github.com/omergul123/LLSimpleCamera/issues/48

I also tried with Apple's code "AvCam", and I still have the same issue. How does Snapchat do this?!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, and I'll gladly provide more info or code!

Comment: Did you find a solution? I need the same thing and can't achieve it.

Comment: I found a solution, but it's not optimal. I add the audiodeviceInput when I start recording ( [self.session addInput:_audioDeviceInput]; ) and remove it when I'm done. At the same time I set the AVAudioSession Category to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, which I also switch back afterwards. To compensate for the weird camera UI behavior, I fade in and out a blur-view on top.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried. Not optimal as you said. I also tried to keep PlayAndRecord category with MixWithOthers, DuckOthers, DefaultToSpeaker but the background music stops for a second when I init the session. Also the music is too loud (even with Duckothers) and I can't hear well my own sound when it's playing.

Comment: It shouldn't stop if you init the session without audioInput and with AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient. I have AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient without an audioInput which will let you listen to background music while taking a picture and everything else in the app, but won't record sound when recording video. So I add the audioInput when I start recording and at the same time switch to AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord which will fade out the music. (BTW, even Snapchat has crack-sound when switching audiosession if you listen to music when filming. I don't believe there is an optimal solution)

Answer (score 5):

I do something similar to what you're wanting, but without the camera aspect, but I think this will do what you want. My app allows background audio that will mix with non-fullscreen video/audio. When the user plays an audio file or a full screen video file, I stop the background audio completely.

The reason I do **SoloAmbient** then **Playback** is because I allow my audio to be played in the background when the device is locked. Going **SoloAmbient** will stop all background music playing and then switching to **Playback** lets my audio play in the app as well as in the background.

This is why you see a call to a method that sets the lock screen information in the Unload method. In this case, it is nulling it out so that there is no lock screen info.

**In AppDelegate.swift**

```
//MARK: Audio Session Mixing
func allowBackgroundAudio()
{
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, withOptions: .MixWithOthers)
    } catch {
        NSLog("AVAudioSession SetCategory - Playback:MixWithOthers failed")
    }
}

func preventBackgroundAudio()
{
    do {
        //Ask for Solo Ambient to prevent any background audio playing, then change to normal Playback so we can play while locked
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    } catch {
        NSLog("AVAudioSession SetCategory - SoloAmbient failed")
    }
}
```

When I want to stop background audio, for example when playing an audio track that should be alone, I do the following:

**In MyAudioPlayer.swift**

```
func playUrl(url: NSURL?, backgroundImageUrl: NSURL?, title: String, subtitle: String) 
{
    ForgeHelper.appDelegate().preventBackgroundAudio()

    if _mediaPlayer == nil {
        self._mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
        _mediaPlayer!.delegate = self
    }

    //... Code removed for brevity
}
```

And when I'm done with my media playing, I do this:

```
private func unloadMediaPlayer()
{
    if _mediaPlayer != nil {
        _mediaPlayer!.unload()
        self._mediaPlayer = nil
    }

    _controlView.updateForProgress(0, duration: 0, animate: false)

    ForgeHelper.appDelegate().allowBackgroundAudio()
    setLockScreenInfo()
}
```

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, it's different when dealing with a camera because the camera requires audio-input. According to the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH10-SW1) the AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback only allows output. Using your example code, the background music plays fine, but the camera won't start.